# QGIS 2.14 Essen Scale Setting Problem

Tags: qgis, scale

The scale of the canvas plot shows in the status bar as everyone knows. However If I want to change the scale it refuses to work properly.  This occurs whether I select a scale from the drop-down menu of standard scales or type in my own desired scale.  QGIS seems to have its own set of irregular values such as 1:577,790 and 1:144,447 and refuses to accept that I type in or select. 
Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predefine your own scale you can go to `Settings -> Options > Map Tools`, and in the predefined scale section, you can add the scale that you want. But the scale in the map/data viewing window depends on the projection that you are using in your data.

Comment: The problem only seems to occur with a projected datum.  Geographic seems to be OK.  Further work needed.

Comment: Could you try to load the in a new project, and check if you have the same issue?

Comment: Thanks ahmadhanb.  Problem seems likely to have been OpenLayers but not absolutely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the OpenLayers plugin installed? That can result in this behaviour.

Comment: Yes I do have OpenLayers installed.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: My advice - uninstall OpenLayers and install "Quick Map Services" instead. It's like a much less buggy + actively maintained version of the OpenLayers plugin.

Comment: Uninstalled OpenLayers but made no difference.

Comment: OpenLayers still uninstalled but all working OK now.  Able to set whatever scale I like.

Comment: Will try Quick Map Services and report how I go.  Thanks ndawson.

Comment: Discovered that both OpenLayers and Quick Map Services had been installed when the problem surfaced.  OpenLayers now uninstalled, Quick Map Services still installed and scaling works fine.  Thanks to all.

Comment: The problem has resurfaced after seeming to work OK for a while. OpenLayers has been uninstalled, W\Quick Map Services is installed. When I select scale 1:5000 from drop-down, or if I type 1:5000 in the box, it displays 1:4513, 1:10,000 shows 1:9027, 1:25,000 gives 1:18,055.  Strange?